# Dismiss a imagepickercontroller

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, viewcontroller

I'm trying to dismiss a imagepickercontroller (album or camera) which is presented as below

```
    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

By calling :

```
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I can't dismiss the imagepickercontroller.

Any body can help me on this?

Comment: You need to call [**imagePicker** dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; in imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: or imagePickerControllerDidCancel:.

Comment: That will be good if u can post this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
else
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Don't know whether the NULL rather than nil would matter, but it should be nil.

The picker is presented with the following code:

```
- (void)getVideoFromDevice
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)  // for ipad only
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        imagePicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];;
        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
        [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems objectAtIndex:0] permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
    else    // for iphone only - NOT TESTED
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code for iPhone yet but the iPad portion is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dismiss the `UIImagePickerViewController` in the delegate methods: `imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` and `imagePickerControllerDidCancel:`. Just be sure to assign the `UIImagePickerViewController` delegate to the `UIViewController` that presents the `UIImagePickerViewController`.

**Example:**

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *) picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```